# How to fix fontd process taking up 100% of the CPU?

Tags: macos, performance, font, font-book

I experience reoccurring incidents of `fontd` eating up all the process power. What could be the cause of this and how do I make it behave again?

Answer (score 5):

`sudo atsutil databases -remove; atsutil server -shutdown`

From 50% cpu usage to 1%

Source: http://icicity.com/2014/02/13/high-cpu-usage-caused-by-fontd-on-os-x

Comment: This should be followed by a restart.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for defective fonts. I believe there are apps that can help with that. "Doctoring" is the term used often

Answer (score 0):

Do [the following](https://support.apple.com/guide/font-book/restore-fonts-that-came-with-your-mac-fb34862/mac) and place your removed fonts back to the "font" folder of your library folder.

> Restore fonts that came with your Mac using Font Book
> You can restore the fonts that were originally included with your Mac. This may be useful if you’re having issues with Font Book. Restoring the standard fonts moves any fonts you’ve installed into a separate folder, which makes them unavailable to use in apps.
>
> In the Font Book app  on your Mac, choose File > Restore Standard Fonts.
>
> Any fonts you’ve installed are placed in /Library/Fonts (Removed) or in ~/Library/Fonts (Removed). To install those fonts again, just reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do `rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontRegistry.user.plist` and 90 percent I sure that your problem will be resolved!

Comment: What is the purpose of this plist and what will I loose if I delete it?

Comment: plist stores some preferences and if you delete it, the default preference take its place!